# Как сделать возможность копировать текст с элемента в ListBox (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListBox, в нем есть элементы, мне нужно сделать так, что бы текст элемента, который я выделил (т.е. нажал на него) копировался в буфер обмена при нажатии ctrl + c. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

```
<Window x:Class="Encrypt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Encrypt"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" SizeToContent="Width">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="650"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Ключ"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="CodeWord"/>
        <Button Content="Зашифровать" Click="EncryptButtonClick" Height="30"/>
        <Button Content="Дешифровать" Click="DescryptButtonClick" Height="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox x:Name="InputText"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="OutputTextList"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace Encrypt
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Encryption encryption = new Encryption();
    Descyption descyption = new Descyption();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void EncryptButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
        item.Content = encryption.StartEncryption(InputText.Text, CodeWord.Text);
        OutputTextList.Items.Add(item);
    }

    void DescryptButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
        item.Content = descyption.StartDescryption(InputText.Text, CodeWord.Text);
        OutputTextList.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
}
```

Вот код, который связан с WPF. Это простая программа по шифровке. Вводишь Текст, кодовое слово, оно шифруется, и результат выводится в ListBox.
Так выглядит сама программа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я хочу узнать, как добавить возможность копировать текст выделенного элемента

Comment: Создайте минимальный пример на базе пустого приложения, покажите разметку и код. А так, `InputBindings` и `SelectedItem` вам помогут. Не заставляйте отвечающего писать код с нуля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна возможность выделять мышью текст у объекта `ListBox`, то его надо стилизовать под `TextBox`, задав ему привязку и режим `IsReadOnly`, примерно так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Так мы получим стандартное поведение, которое позволит выделить текст и скопировать его горячими клавишами:

[image: Result 1]

Если нам надо копировать выделенный объект именно сочетанием клавиш, то для этого надо установить `InputBindings`, который будет привязывать сочетание клавиш к команде и уже разметка будет такой:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="C"
            Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Items/}" />
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Обратите внимание на `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`, это позволяет получить текущий выбранный элемент при помощи простого `Items/`.
Результат:

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!